# Where should I put the bool method that checks if it's iphone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is pretty basic stuff but what I'm doing doesn't feels right so I'm asking the experts.

I have a boolean method that checks if the user is on iphone 5

`- (BOOL)isTall
{
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat height = bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    return (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && ((height * scale) >= 1136));}`

I've placed it in another class called stuff.m and I'm importing it to every other class i'm using and firing it up like this:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DataManager *testMe = [[DataManager alloc]init];
    if(test.isTall)
        NSLog(@"Hey");`

Is that the proper way to go? seems like there should be a better way doing so without allocating `testMe` in every class.

Comment: paste this function in your appDelegate class, and access it wherever you require..

Comment: I tried doing it but the other classes doesn't recognize it. Do i need to have a plus sign at the beginning like the other answer suggested.

Comment: No, not required. You need to declare your function in .h file.

Comment: I have the method in the appdelegate. in the h file i have `- (BOOL)isTall;` In a separate class I have `if(self.isTall)` that is not recognized.

Comment: Make you instance to appDelegate in this way AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: I completely lost you. Where should i put that instance? Do I need to import my `appDelegate` class?

Comment: yes in your class file import "AppDelegate.h" file and use this code wherever you require. For accessing function, you can use [appDelegate isTall];

Comment: So what do i benefit from this? What's the difference between using the appDelegate or putting it in another class and importing it?

Comment: You are allocating your class every time for no use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in your `UIApplicationDelegate`

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 ((([UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Import it to your class of choice.

```
#import "yourAppDelegate.h"
```

And from within a codeblock you just do this!

```
if (IS_IPHONE5) 
{
   NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
}
```

Comment: I've added the code to my appDelegate.h. I've imported my appDelegate.h to the required class but when I try to use `    if(IS_IPHONE5) NSLog(@"Hey");` I'm getting Expected ')' .. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

place it in the utility class. make a class called utility and place it inside that class and make it a class function.

```
+(bool)isIPhone5{ method };
```

By this way you can use it anywhere.even the utility class can be reused for further projects.
and to use this use it in view did load function for change in implementation or init function if there is any init changes

```
[className isIPhone5];
```

will give you the result if you have imported the header and declared it in the.h file

Answer (score 1):

Use a class member `+ (BOOL)isTall` and call it with `[Stuff isTall]`.  Note that when this module contains only helper class methods, you don't need to allocate it ever and a `- (id)init` is not needed.

Comment: Where do I put it? In my delegate? please read the comment to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this method in app delegate and store the result in NSUserDefault as a boolean value. Then you can access it anywhere in the application.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Just because you can put this in your AppDelegate doesn't mean that this is a good place to put it! Code should be structured meaningfully. Code in the AppDelegate should reflect the implemented protocols of the UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: I agree.. I was trying to suggest NSUserDefault primarily.

Answer (score 1):

Every app has a class called AppDelegate, which contains a method called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

}
```

Whenever the app has finished launching, this method executes. But your method in here and store the BOOL in NSUserDefaults, something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.isIPhone5 forKey:@"isIPhone5"];
```

Then you can get the value of this default setting by doing the following:

```
self.isIPhone5 = [defaults boolForKey:@"isIPhone5"];
```